# ExtJS: data[root].slice is not a function error after adding tpl and store to dataview

Tags: html, extjs

I have a template, a store and a simple dataview to which I add the store and tpl. Im unable to run it and getting the following error: data[root].slice is not a function.

Heres my fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/cc9

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Store was in the wrong format, you can't have dynamic columns the way you are setting up when your model is already static.

This should fix your problems:

```
var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
   fields:["VAL", "HEAT"],
   autoLoad:true,
   proxy:{
    type:"ajax",
    url:"data1.json",
    reader:{
      type:"json",
      root:"data.ROWS"

    }
  }
 });
    var myTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(

 '<table border="1px" border-color="#444444" width="100%">',
    '<tr>',
        '<th>VAL</th>',
         '<th>HEAT</th>',
    '</tr>',
    '<tpl for=".">',
       '<tr>',
            '<td align="center">{VAL}</td>',
            '<td align="center">{HEAT}</td>',
       '</tr>',
     '</tpl>',
 '</table>'
 );

 var dataview = Ext.create("Ext.view.View",{
    store: store,
    tpl:myTpl,
    itemSelector:"",
    renderTo:Ext.getBody()

});
```

And your data1.json

```
{
    "data" : {

      "COLUMNS": [
         "Column 1",
         "Column 2",
         "Column 3"
       ],


      "ROWS": [
          {"VAL":"R1C1", "HEAT":1}, 
          {"VAL":"R1C2", "HEAT":3}, 
          {"VAL":"R1C3", "HEAT":2},
          {"VAL":"R2C1", "HEAT":1}, 
          {"VAL":"R2C2", "HEAT":1}, 
          {"VAL":"R2C3", "HEAT":4}
      ]

     }
}
```